# Xamarin unable to Connect to Web Service

Tags: xamarin, vpn

I am running Xamarin on a computer that is connected to a VPN.  I can browse web services from an internet browser that are inside the VPN.  However, when I run Xamarin, I get the following error that shows up in Visual Studio:

System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Network is unreachable)

Is there something else that needs to be set up for Xamarin so that it finds these web services?  Or does the Emulator specifically need to get set up to connect to the VPN as well?

Comment: iOS or Android?  Debug or Release mode?

Comment: Are you talking about your device/emulator throwing that error? If so, it needs to be connected to your VPN just like your PC is...

Comment: This is Android in Debug mode using a built in Emulator.

Comment: It's still unclear _where_ you see this error: in Xamarin Studio / Visual Studio? On Mac or on Windows? When deploying an app to a device/emulator or when trying to access a web service from within your app running on a device/emulator/simulator? Please update your question with relevant information, otherwise it will be hard to assist.